# Could not build Spring boot app with cache and pub sub with Kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe

I am working upon one e-commerce Spring boot app with spring integration, spring web.

my requirement is to develop the Spring App which is sort of e-commerce app but I am not able to find good reference to build this.

my requirement is below:

**A number of vendors provide price information for product; a product will have different prices from different vendors. Price data from each vendor is to be cached in a local data store(mysql) and then distributed to interested downstream systems. The cache will have services to allow clients to publish and retrieve data from the store. Clients are interested in getting all prices from a particular vendor or prices for a single product from various vendors. Prices older than 30 days must be removed from the cache**

I want to use **Spring boot(or spring integration)** with **caching** along with **pub-sub** mechanism in it with **Kafka**.

how can I develop such an App, any leads or reference would be highly appreciated.

-Thanks

Comment: You can use Kafka for downstream but I would rather put it before your component. Currently, You want a REST API that works like a query. I can imagine every vendor sends price information into Kafka, and you read and save them.